# CloudMQTT python in Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I'm trying create something with my Raspberry pi where if I do one action I send a MQTT message to the CloudMQTT so who is listening this knows what to do.

In one example is :
User 1 press button RBP knows it, and sends a MQTT message to CloudMQTT and the other RBP detects that User 1 pressed a button so User 2 know when to press the button.

What I did is :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userData, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("MyInstanceName/topic")

def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    print(msg.topic+ " "+ str(msg.payload))
    if(msg.payload == "button"):
        print("something")
    if(msg.payload == "button2"):
        print("something")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set("user","password")
client.connect("m21.cloudmqtt.com",port,60)
client.loop_forever()
```

I created two `Users and ACL` because I only need 2 users, so I created User1 with a topic and can read/write also for the User2

What I don't know how to is the publish because I have this :

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("MyInstanceName/topic","button",hostname="m21.cloudmqtt.com")
publish.single("MyInstanceName/topic","button2",hostname="m21.cloudmqtt.com")
print("Done")
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_publisher.py", line 3, in <module>
    publish.single("MyInstanceName/topic","button",hostname="m21.cloudmqtt.com")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 223, in single
    protocol, transport)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/publish.py", line 159, in multiple
    client.connect(hostname, port, keepalive)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Now is all hardcoded, but when I connect a button into my RBP how do I have to detect this button click? I can still using Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [doc](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#single) for the `publish.single` function you will see it can take an argument called `auth` which holds the username/password to connect to the broker

> **auth**
>
> a dict containing authentication parameters for the client:
>
> auth = {‘username’:””, ‘password’:””}
>
> Username is required, password is optional and will default to None if
>   not provided.
>
> Defaults to None, which indicates no authentication is to be used.